# Java JSONArray throws unexpected exception

Tags: java, json

I need to convert JSON generated in JavaScript to a JSONArray in Java - the context here is a Cordova plugin for a hybrid Android app.  The following string

```
 "[\"9784142605765949528\",2869,264,7]"
```

causes Java to complain.  It comes back with the message

> ["9784142605765949528",2869,264,7]
> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

I fail to see why this might be happening.  The first array element above is a string though it looks like a number.  This is because I am using a custom 64 bit integer implementation in JS which returns its value as a string.

The part of my Java code that is parsing this JSON is as follows

```
try
   {
    Feedback.postBackInfo("LWPD4 " + lwpd[4]); 
    JSONArray hXYZ = new JSONArray(lwpd[4]);
```

`Feedback` is an internal utility I use to aid with debugging.  The JSON I show below comes from that call to `Feedback` and it is the subsequent `new JSONArray()` that is throwing this error

I fail to see what is wrong here - the string *is* valid JSON.

Comment: That was a typo as I composed this question.  I have now corrected it.  The JSON is being generated in JS by `JSON.stringify`ing an array so it is unlikely to be invalid.

Comment: Show the code you are using to parse the string.

Comment: See my answer. There is nothing wrong with the json you include in your question, it can be parsed without issue. The problem is that that is not the string you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might be confused about the input String you are trying to parse. The following codes works just fine.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class JsonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String json = "[\"9784142605765949528\",2869,264,7]";
        JSONArray result = new JSONArray(json);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Since the above works I suspect that you are not trying to parse the String you think you are trying to parse. What is the actual value of your `lwpd[4]` variable?

Comment: You are right. The full context here is as follows - the JSON is being generated by Duktape working from within a Cordova plugin in a hybrid Android app.  The JSON **IS** valid.  One could argue that mixing types in an array is not in keeping with the philosophy of Java but should still work in a JSONArray.  I have been unable to figure out just why that generated JSON is not being parsed by Java.  In the end I just created a simple helper class to parse the JSON into one string and three ints - I have the benefit of knowing what to expect here so I can do that.